# How to diagnose eclipse crashes?

Tags: eclipse, jvm, crash

OMG, eclipse (it's Gallileo, but with previous versions I also had such problems) crashed again, silently as always. That can happen one time per week, but this is really annoying. All I have now is a crash log. Are there any ways of discovering the true reason of these crashes?

Header of crash log, can't see anything useful:

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d80f8d4, pid=1388, tid=3180
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0_12-b04 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xcf8d4]
#
```

Comment: Did you try starting Eclipse from a command line prompt? I usually get a full stack trace of where the crash occurred, and THEN the header of the crash log that you posted above.

Answer (score 2):

For Galileo, I would recommend trying to launch it with the most recent JVM possible;

That does not mean you have to compile your projects with that JDK: you can declare as many JDK you want within your eclipse session.

[image]
<sub>(source: [benmccann.com](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/eclipse_edit_jre.png))</sub>

(although this picture shows jdk1.5, you can launch eclipse with any other JVM)

See this [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-eclipse-34-jvm-settings#144349) for more details.

---

As this recent [thread illustrates](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg28898.html), that can happens with an "old" eclipse.ini, so it is worth checking and updating the ini file.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have these kind of silent crashes on 64-bit Linux. For me it was fine after adding these lines to my eclipse.ini (see corresponding [Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=214092) and [Sun](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6614100) bug entries):

```
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,<init>
```

Comment: This got me further into the startup process running 64bit 1.5_22. it still crashes but less often and not right at startup. I think it has something to do with the build process eclipse undergoes when it starts.

Comment: I *think* that adding this to the eclipse.ini made it more stable on my 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04. I am using "adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321" android development bundle which is very unstable out of the box (crashes during normal developemnt, maybe 2-3 each hour if you are unlucky. No stack trace, eclipse just exits).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Sun's Java VM which Eclipse triggers. These are notoriously hard to figure out. I suggest this approach:

1. Install a newer VM (1.5.0 *16* or 1.6)
2. Disable all plugins you've installed
3. I had a similar issue with Groovy on Linux. I don't remember my solution but try a different version of Groovy in this case.